# How to access data in Django which models is not defined in models.py?

Tags: database, django

I have configured database properly. If I want to access the data from the table `hello` in the database called `genes`. What's the proper way to do it? I can't do from `books.models import hello` as I don't have hello in models.py. The database genes and table hello is not the default Django database. I have two databases. I have already setup `Router`. I want to now access data. How can I do that? Thanks

Comment: Not much. Anyway thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to do a few things..

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'genes': {
        'ENGINE':   'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME':     'genes',
        'USER':     'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST':     'localhost',
        'PORT':     '3360',
    },
    'default': {
        'ENGINE':   'django.db.backends.mysql',
        'NAME':     'django',
        'USER':     'root',
        'PASSWORD': 'root',
        'HOST':     'localhost',
        'PORT':     '3360',
    }
}

DATABASE_ROUTERS = ['genes.routers.GeneRouter',]
```

routers.py

```
class GeneRouter(object):
    """A router to control all database operations on models in
    the genes application"""

    def db_for_read(self, model, **hints):
        "Point all operations on genes models to 'genes'"
        if model._meta.app_label == 'genes':
            return 'remrate'
        return None

    def db_for_write(self, model, **hints):
        "Point all operations on genes models to 'genes'"
        if model._meta.app_label == 'genes':
            return 'remrate'
        return None

    def allow_syncdb(self, db, model):
        "Make sure the genes app only appears on the 'genes' db"
        if model._meta.app_label in ['south']:
            return True
        if db == 'remrate':
            return model._meta.app_label == 'genes'
        elif model._meta.app_label == 'genes':
            return False
        return None
```

One you have this set up then you need to create the models.py file for the

models.py

```
class Hello(models.Model):
    """Hello model"""

    field1 = models.CharField(max_length=64)

    class Meta:
        db_table = u'hello'
        managed = False
```

To do this progmatically..

```
python manage.py inspectdb
```

Once this is done - you should be able to Query using standard Django querysets

```
Hello.objects.all()
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I had already configured settings.py and added router. Why would I want to create another model? I already have tables and databases. I don't want to recreate models.

Comment: You need the model as that is how Django connect to the db.  Wait don't forget the meta option

Comment: You can create a model in models.py to represent an existing database and table.  That is the typical way to resolve this issue.  (You can alternatively just connect to the database outside of the Django ORM entirely by using a database driver directly.)

Comment: Yeah, it can be done Pythonic way using MYSQLdb module. But I wanted to know if there's a Django way to do that. Is there a tutorial to create a model to represent existing database and tables.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewGorcester. That's exactly what I want.