# Django - How can Django ORM manage user's uploaded tables in database

Tags: django, django-models

My web application allow users to load/create tables in the Postgres database. I know Django ORM needs a model definition in models.py for each table in the database to access it. How can I access the user's uploaded tables in the app without creating a new model definition on the fly each time a new table is uploaded? I was thinking about creating a generic model definition that decompose the table into its components like this:

models.py

```
class Table(models.Model):
    filename = models.CharField(max_length=255)

class Attribute(models.Model):
    table = models.ForeignKey(Table)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=255)
    type = models.IntegerField()
    width = models.IntegerField()
    precision = models.IntegerField()

class Row(models.Model):
    table = models.ForeignKey(Table)

class AttributeValue(models.Model):
    row = models.ForeignKey(Row)
    attribute = models.ForeignKey(Attribute)
    value = models.CharField(max_length=255, blank=True, null=True)
```

The problems with such a generic model is that every tables are mixed in 4 table (not useful in admin interface) and its really slow to create when you have a lot of rows. Do you have suggestion with this case?

**Edit:** Could it be viable to use a separate database to store those tables and use a router and `manage.py inspectdb` to update its models.py each time a user add or delete a table? ([like in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14108003/how-to-access-data-in-django-which-models-is-not-defined-in-models-py)) I wonder what would happen if two users add a table in the same time?

Comment: I'm not getting if your main problem is how to let the user create his tables or how you can define models to handle the tables the users are  creating.

Comment: Main problem is how to handle the tables with Django ORM. I was thinking about calling inspectdb after upload (or delete) but Im not sure if its the best solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you should look into dynamic models like here:

https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/DynamicModels

or here:

http://dynamic-models.readthedocs.org/en/latest/

Good luck because its not an easy way my friend :)

Answer (score 2):

You'll probably need to use [raw SQL queries](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/sql/) for doing this.

If the schema of the tables you are expecting are predefined you can use a database router to link some model to a specific table name for each user.